# Unable to access nested attributes on object in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am having difficulty accessing nested data from an object in a React/Redux application.

The specific page is a 'profile' page detailing the information about a patient.

A `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method is used to call a redux action which sends an axios.get request to the express backend. A JSON object is returned and the reducer transfers this to the redux state. The redux state is as below (note the structure of the 'patient' object - this is the object I am accessing.

```
Redux
|-- auth
|   |-- isAuthenticated
|   +-- user
|       |-- name
|       |-- id
|       +-- isAdmin
|-- patients
|   |-- patients [ls of 'patient' objects] -> not relevant to this component
|   +-- patient
|       |-- name
|       |-- dateOfBirth
|       +-- contact
|           |-- phone
|           |-- email
|           +-- address
+-- errors
```

In the `render()`, I pull the 'patient' object out of the redux state:

```
const { patient } = this.props.patients;
```

and then use the 'patient' object in the `return()`. If I refer to a 'top-level' attribute (eg. name or dateOfBirth) it works fine. However, when I try to access a nested attribute (eg. phone, email or address) it fails with the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined
```

If I remove the `{patient.contact.address}` from the code below, the component renders fine - including the references to `{patient.name}` and `{patient.dateOfBirth}` put it back in and it fails.

I have tried pulling the 'contact' object out of props also and that fails. All the data is in the redux state as expected when it loads - and if I `console.log(patient)` immediately after pulling it from props, the browser console shows all the data (nothing mising).

Why am I able to get the top-level attributes of the patient object, but not the nested ones?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Moment from 'react-moment';

import { getPatientById } from '../../redux/actions/patient.actions';

class PatientDetailed extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    if (this.props.match.params.patient_id) {
      this.props.getPatientById(this.props.match.params.patient_id);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { patient } = this.props.patients;

    return (
      <>
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-body">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-6">
                  <h6>Name:</h6>
                </div>
                <div className="col-6">{patient.name}</div>
              </div>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-6">
                  <h6>Date of birth:</h6>
                </div>
                <div className="col-6">
                  <Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY">{patient.dateOfBirth}</Moment>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-6">
                  <h6>Address:</h6>
                </div>
                <div className="col-6">{patient.contact.address}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

PatientDetailed.propTypes = {
  getPatientById: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  patients: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  patients: state.patients
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getPatientById }
)(PatientDetailed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are fetching the data and updating store in `componentDidMount` method, the contacts object might not be available on first render and hence you get the error. Provide a check for existence before using

```
<div className="col-6">{patient.contact && patient.contact.address}</div>
```

Comment: That Worked - Thanks @Shubham! Can you explain what that syntax is actually doing? Is the `patient.contact &&` working like a conditional or something?

Comment: It's a common pattern in React that takes advantage that the values `null` and `false` are ignored when rendering a React component. When the expression `patient.contact && patient.contact.address` is evaluated, it first evaluates the left state statement. In the case`patient.contact` is undefined, it doesn't bother evaluating the rest of the expression since an expression `false && anything` can't be true so it returns undefined and is therefore ignored by React. In the case `patient.contact` exists, it also evaluates `patient.contact.address` and return it

Comment: Here's a better explanation: https://codeburst.io/javascript-logical-operators-cd50a5df0fc7